# How to stop trigger animation when player colliding the ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a new unity's user, and I'm trying to make a little 2D plateformer.
I can controle my player but I have a little problem with my jump.

I made it with a trigger in animator, it works, but I want to stop the animation when player touching the ground.

The best will be to keep the last jump's frame prep until the player touch the ground, and after stop it.

I have a collider2D on a gameObjet who's attached to the player with this code:

```
  void Start()
{
    Audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    Anim = transform.parent.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Sol" || col.gameObject.tag == "Plateforme")
    {
        Anim.SetTrigger("stopJump");
        transform.parent.GetComponent<playerController>().isGrounded = true;
        Audio.pitch = 0.7f;
        Audio.volume = 0.7f;
        Audio.PlayOneShot(soundGround);
    }
}
```

My animator have a transition 'stopJump' between 'jump' 'idle' and run. Is it the right thing to do?
[see my animator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoYhA.png)

The animation Jump doesn't want to stop before the ending frame. If i disable 'has exit time', the jump stop too early...
The trigger 'stopJump' does not have priority...

Thanks!

Comment: Better if you ask your question on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your state machine of the animator,

just add an idle state and a trigger which will transfer from JUMP state to that IDLE(which will loop when the player is standing on the ground and do nothing) state, then from the `OnTriggerEnter2D` you could use Animator.setTrigger("triggerName") to transfer the state to idle.

As in our project player should become idle in lots of condition, so we just made an AnyStat transfer to the idle state by trigging `backIdel` here is the example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is still a probleme with it... I updated my question if you can help me again... Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I think you maybe take me wrong , there should be no need to make another *stopJump* state, a trigger from jump state to idle state is all you need, in our project for the convinces purpose we even made a trigger from **anystate**  to idle  which will allow us to transfer to idle state whatever state we previously was.

Comment: Glad that could help :D

Comment: Hi, first select the gameobject in hierarchy then under the top menu of **GameObject** there should be a `Break Prefab Instance` Option, that may help

Comment: Okay! I found it! Thanks!! You're my hero! haha

Comment: Okay it doesn't work..
1. I duplicate "ennemie3"
2. I rename it "ennemie2"
3. I click on it > GameObjet> Break preface instance
4. I create a new pref and drop "ennemie2" in

but when i modify ennemie2 after that, ennemie3 is changing too...

When i click on the gameobject 'ennemie2' and click on 'select' in inspector, the prefab il 'ennemie2', same for "ennemie3" it's prefab "ennemie3"..

Comment: that is wired, what did you change? is it the material?

Comment: I Just changed sprite pics in animation

Comment: they are using the same animator right? Well, they shouldn't, you should duplicate the animator and animation too

Comment: as my experience, you can't do that, you should make different animations according to the type of enemy, though, the [animator override controller](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimatorOverrideController.html) may help you a bit since they share the same control logic, but I think you should make different animations according to the enemy type

Comment: Thanks for your help. you were right, i have to create manually a new animator because i can't just replace animation after duplication.. :)